# Concatenation macro in C++

Tags: c++, macros, concatenation, c-preprocessor

I have the following definition in my C++ file:

```
#define SIZE 32
```

And I want to generate following two lines:

```
typedef uint32_t bui
typedef uint64_t lui
```

The first line can be generated by:

```
#define PASTER(x,y) x ## y ## _t
#define EVALUATOR(x,y)  PASTER(x,y)
#define NAME(fun, size) EVALUATOR(fun, size)

typedef NAME(uint,SIZE) bui
```

But I cant't generate the second line with

```
typedef NAME(uint,SIZE*2) lui
```

Is it possible to do it without defining `#define DOUBLE_SIZE 64`, using only `SIZE` macro?

Comment: uint32_t and uint64_t are fix-size integers. Why not to use `unsigned long` to get the given value?
Macros are replacement in the code, you cannot make compiler time operations like multiplication at this stage.

Comment: Why use macros at all? Isn't this an ideal case for templates?

Comment: You can just use `boost::int_t<SIZE>` and `boost::int_t<SIZE*2>` here

Comment: C++ does not work this way.

Comment: @AdrianMaire "you cannot make compiler time operations like multiplication at this stage" [I wouldn't quite go _that_ far](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/646172dda395fb1b)

Comment: @HWalters: nice exercise, it is a bit in the border of what I call macros (using #if, etc..) but interesting.

Comment: @AdrianMaire There are [other approaches](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4ed6d12dfbc2a0c4) that use only `#define`, but this is just a curiosity.  My main point is to dispel the notion that the CPP can't do math.  (Of course, at some point if we continue you're going to phrase exactly what you think the CPP can't do, and I'm just going to wind up agreeing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefer templates over macros where possible (almost always):

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdint>

struct Signed {};
struct Unsigned{};


namespace detail {
    template<class SignedNess, std::size_t Bits> struct make_int ;
    template<> struct make_int<Signed, 64> { using type = std::int64_t; };
    template<> struct make_int<Signed, 32> { using type = std::int32_t; };
    template<> struct make_int<Signed, 16> { using type = std::int16_t; };
    template<> struct make_int<Signed, 8> { using type = std::int8_t; };
    template<> struct make_int<Unsigned, 64> { using type = std::uint64_t; };
    template<> struct make_int<Unsigned, 32> { using type = std::uint32_t; };
    template<> struct make_int<Unsigned, 16> { using type = std::uint16_t; };
    template<> struct make_int<Unsigned, 8> { using type = std::uint8_t; };
}

template<class Signedness, std::size_t Bits> using make_int = typename detail::make_int<Signedness, Bits>::type;

int main()
{
    make_int<Signed, 16> x = 5;
}
```

Comment: IMHO: Be careful with sentences like "Prefer X over Y". Each tool has its purpose, and because of claims like this, I found people making absolutely crazy stuff (e.g. simulating inheritance by aggregation). Additionally, (and here I will get killed by the C++ community) templates is a dangerous tool, making compilation some times very difficult to debug, nearly as dangerous as macros.